# How to stack xyplots in jfreechart

Tags: java, plot, jfreechart

I am new to jfreecharts. I have 3 functions and their sum plotted in one chart. This works fine (like http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartXYLogAxesDemo.htm except that my x axis is linear).

Now I would like to vary one parameter of these function over a small range. I would like to see something like  http://www.originlab.com/www/resources/graph_gallery/images_galleries/Choe_as_3D_Waterfall_500px.gif or this bar graph http://www.statsref.com/HTML/bars3d_demo.png where each xy plane would have the 4 functions plotted on it.

I could perhaps use some kind of bar chart to combine the 4 functions like http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/Images/Chart_Working_2D_Stacked_Column_Chart_Data_01.png, so a stacked series of these might work.

Failing that, how would one get jfreechart to display an matrix chart? Is there some stuff built in to jfreechart or does one have to make a bunch of chart panels and add them to a panel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you how to do it in JFreeChart, but in [XChart](https://github.com/timmolter/XChart) it's very simple to create a chart matrix like you described.

Take a look at [Example 4: Create a Chart Matrix](http://xeiam.com/xchart_examplecode.jsp).

The code would look something like this:

```
int numCharts = 4;

List<Chart> charts = new ArrayList<Chart>();

for (int i = 0; i < numCharts; i++) {
  charts.add(QuickChart.getChart("" + i, "X", "Y", null, null, getRandomWalk(1000)));
}
new SwingWrapper(charts).displayChartMatrix();
```

, where `getRandomWalk(1000)` would need to be replaced by your own y-axis data set.

Comment: thanks, i may try this if i can't find an easy way to solve this using jfreechart

Comment: i did try this and it's very easy to do. but i can't get the plots in the different windows to have the same range on the y axis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767577/how-to-make-limits-on-the-y-axis-be-the-same-using-xchart

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and discovered this code snippet:
[CombinedDomainXYPlot](http://www.google.de/imgres?um=1&client=firefox-a&sa=N&rls=org.mozilla%3ade%3aofficial&hl=de&biw=1920&bih=917&tbm=isch&tbnid=83WSnYtwk-B4eM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartCombinedXYPlotDemo1.htm&docid=0hALjGfmEbOuyM&imgurl=http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaImages/JFreeChartCombinedXYPlotDemo5.PNG&w=508&h=297&ei=gm-ZUdm7MoSC4gTIxYAY&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=218&vpy=135&dur=3765&hovh=172&hovw=294&tx=194&ty=102&page=1&tbnh=134&tbnw=229&start=0&ndsp=42&ved=1t:429,r:1,s:0,i:87)

It uses a "CombinedDomainXYPlot" to achieve it.