# How to make limits on the Y axis be the same using XChart?

Tags: java, plot, charts, knowm-xchart

I am trying to plot a series of functions that are similar. The domain is [0,1] and the range always in say [-3,3].

I want the limits on the Y axis to be the same for each graph. Trying to set the series y min and y max does not seem to work.

Is there a way to make the limits on the Y axis be the same on each graph?

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.*;
import com.xeiam.xchart.*;
public class Bug {
    static void plot(Chart chart,int n) {
        chart.setTitle("title");
        chart.setXAxisTitle("X");
        chart.setYAxisTitle("Y");
        List<Number> x=new ArrayList<Number>();
        List<Number> y=new ArrayList<Number>();
        String seriesName=addOneSeries(chart,n,x,y);
    }
    private static String addOneSeries(Chart chart,int n,List<Number> x,List<Number> y) {
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
            x.add(i/10.);
            y.add(i*n/10.);
        }
        String seriesName="series "+n;
        Series series=chart.addSeries(seriesName,x,y);
        series.xMin=BigDecimal.ZERO;
        series.xMax=BigDecimal.ONE;
        series.yMin=new BigDecimal(-5);
        series.yMax=new BigDecimal(5);
        return seriesName;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            Chart chart=new Chart(700,500);
            plot(chart,i);
            new SwingWrapper(chart).displayChart();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This functionality doesn't yet exist. I opened a feature request for it in [Github](https://github.com/timmolter/XChart/issues/19).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the min and max values on a `Chart` is now possible with [XChart](http://xeiam.com/xchart.jsp). Below is a rework of OP's Bug class that demonstrates this. At this moment, since it's a brand new feature, you'll have to get an xchart-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT jar [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/com/xeiam/xchart/xchart/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/) in order to see this capability. Please feel free to [ask for help or request more features](https://github.com/timmolter/XChart/issues?state=open)!

```
public class NoBug {

  static void plot(Chart chart, int n) {

    chart.setChartTitle("title");
    chart.setXAxisTitle("X");
    chart.setYAxisTitle("Y");
    List<Number> x = new ArrayList<Number>();
    List<Number> y = new ArrayList<Number>();
    String seriesName = addOneSeries(chart, n, x, y);
  }

  private static String addOneSeries(Chart chart, int n, List<Number> x, List<Number> y) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      x.add(i / 10.);
      y.add(i * n / 10.);
    }
    String seriesName = "series " + n;
    Series series = chart.addSeries(seriesName, x, y);
    chart.getStyleManager().setxAxisMin(0);
    chart.getStyleManager().setxAxisMax(1);
    chart.getStyleManager().setyAxisMin(-5);
    chart.getStyleManager().setyAxisMax(5);
    return seriesName;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      Chart chart = new LineChart(700, 500);
      plot(chart, i);
      new SwingWrapper(chart).displayChart();
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update 2020-10-15

These methods now use a capitalized `X` or `Y`:

```
.setXAxisMin()
.setXAxisMax()
.setYAxisMin()
.setYAxisMax()
```

See https://knowm.org/javadocs/xchart/org/knowm/xchart/style/AxesChartStyler.html#setXAxisMin(java.lang.Double)